# Why is Test Deployment and Actual Deployment different?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, deployment, web-applications

I've been building a webbapp in Google App Script and I have a few copies of the same webapp but with different fields.

When I launch 1 under a TEST DEPLOYMENT it shows up like it should based on the code. But when I have a NEW DEPLOYMENT of the same script it launches a different webapp. Has anyone else had this happen before?

Answer (score 1):

- A test deployment uses the latest code.
- A normal deployment uses the code from the specified version.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#test_a_web_app_deployment

Related

- [Testing Google app script HTML interface without deploying app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20106637/1595451)

Answer (score 0):

I think you click on the **New Deployment**, therefore Google gives you a new link.

If you want to deploy the new version with the same link, you have to click on **Manage Deployments**, then click on the pen figure, after that click on the **New Version.**